# How to set SourceMask size programmatically?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

As this website (https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) says, the expression **?.*** means:

> Give me all the files which have one character as a name, and any
>   extension.

Well, my batch file code actually looks like this:

```
::Rename all elements following the D3 format
for %%a in (?.*) do ren "%%a" "Img_00%%a"
for %%a in (??.*) do ren "%%a" "Img_0%%a"
for %%a in (???.*) do ren "%%a" "Img_%%a"
```

And this smells like I should be able to set the number of interrogations ?????.* with a variable, but I don't know how, and I don't really know if it is possible cause I'm new to batch coding.

Comment: in fact, `?` means "zero or one char". Confusing, but the way the developers chose to go. The `where` command interprets it differently: "exactly one char" (like one would expect)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to fill (numeric?) file names up with leading zeros to have three digits and to add a prefix then. I would do that in a different way:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem /* Loop through all matching files;
rem    this filters for decimal digits: */
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B "???.*" ^| findstr "^[0-9][0-9]*\.[^\.]$"
') do (
    rem // Prepend file name with zeros
    set "NAME=000%%~nF"
    rem // Keep as many digits from the right as necessary:
    ren "%%~F" "Img_!NAME:~-3!%%~xF"
)
endlocal
```

This requires [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for the [sub-string expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) as the variable `NAME` is modified in the same block of code, namely the `for` loop.

The [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) expression constitutes a filter that only accepts file names consisting of decimal digits. If you do not want that, just remove `^|` and the whole `findstr` command line.